# Objective C Runtime - Built-in classes vs custom classes?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I need to be able to differentiate between objective c built in classes, and application specific classes. The way I am making this determination right now is by checking to see if the class name starts with "__", which is a horrible and hacky solution, but it works.

So my question is what is the proper way of figuring out whether a class is a build in class, or an application specific class?

```
//a variable named object is defined already

unsigned int outCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([object class], &outCount);

for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++)
{
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
    id propertyValue = [object valueForKey:(NSString *)propertyName];

    NSString *classString = NSStringFromClass([propertyValue class]);

    if ((classString.length > 2 && [[classString substringToIndex:2] isEqual:@"__"]))
    {
        // Objective C Class (NSString, NSArray, NSDate, NSNumber)
    }
    else
    {
        // Not Objetive C Class
    }
}
```

Comment: **Why?** Why would you want to do this?   There are so many ways that this is a bad idea.

Comment: @bbum I am writing an Object to dictionary mapper. If the Object is a complex object I need to loop thought the properties, and create key/values. If not I need to parse the value directly to a dictionary. The source is here, and there is a warning in the code related to the piece i posted here on line 87. https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper/blob/master/OCMapper/Source/ObjectMapper.m

Comment: Neat stuff (Really-- very cool-- I've been quite deep down the dynamism rabbit hole and this piques my interest!), academically, but do you really need that level of dynamism?   If this is an academic pursuit, dive in!! Otherwise?  Do you really need said abstraction to ensure that your app ships quickly and works?

Comment: More specifically, this kind of dynamism is a gigantic pain in the butt to debug and maintain.  There will be bugs and, often, those bugs will occur on code paths that are exercised 1000s of times before the failure case is hit.   That is the inherent problem with "generic programming".   While the tools support conditionalized debugging, you need to know the condition(s) to break on first and that can be more than half the battle.

Comment: @bbum I agree with your point about debugging issues when it comes to generic programming. I spent hours trouble shooting minor bugs. I think, or at least I hope I am passed that point as far as NSDictionary to Object conversion goes. I've been using this along with AFNetworking in my application without having to do any manual data mapping, and so far I had no issues. The problem I'm facing is on Object to NSDictionary conversion. It's not gonna be easy, but hopefully I can get that part to a usable state where it handles complex-objects and arrays.

Comment: If it's all the same, take a look at how [Mantle](https://github.com/github/Mantle) does JSON conversion.  They do a very good job of enforcing their serialization rules, and given that it only takes implementing a protocol to get serialization to and from an object, I'd say that's the most generic you could ever get trying to do this.  There have to be at least *some* guarantees.  Serialization is a minefield in dynamic languages, though.  NSCoder is all the evidence you need of that.

Comment: I had to implement something like this for objective-cloud. And I took the same approach (without knowing mantle): A class that wants to be automatically serialized (into a JSON object = dictionary) simply has a protocol *ClassName*Publishing, which defines the properties to put in the dictionary. You have the extra feature, that "serializable" properties are a subset of all properties. (Probably someone does not want to serialize every property). It works fine even respecting inheritance.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad That is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I want everything to be automated, unless any customization is needed, but you do have a point on not wanting all properties to be serialized. I really wish objective c supported annotations, it would make life a lot easier.

Comment: Hmm, but wouldn't be annotations something non-automatic. ;-) Over-engeneering is not good. It makes simple things complex. What's wrong in having a protocol with 5, 6 properties to be serialized? It is no work, it is easy to handle, it is linear, so does not grow with the complexity of the whole software system. It is good.

Comment: Maybe there is another solution for you, I use when I do automatic publishing of methods (without using protocols). Since I do not want system-superclasses to be scanned automatically for methods, I added a category on NSObject with a method +scanClassForMethodsAutomatically that returns NO. On some points in class hierarchy I overwrite it to return YES. All subclasses then are scanned automatically. But I do not use this for serialization, because that classes do not have a special superclass and defining a public API through a protocol seems to be more natural und flexibel to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear what you mean by “built in classes”.  Are classes in the Foundation framework “built in”?  What about classes in UIKit?  QuartzCore?  AVFoundation?  Social?

Also, trying to distinguish classes like this seems like a bad idea, unless it's just for learning about the system.

That said, perhaps it will suffice to get the bundle that a class was loaded from.  That will tell you if the class was loaded from Foundation, or UIKit, etc.  Look at [`+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIBGIEG).

Comment: By built in I mean Cocoa classes, anything that was not created by you. Thanks for the response, will try to test against the budle and post back.

Comment: I tried if ([NSBundle bundleForClass:[User class]] == [NSBundle mainBundle]). I tested it with "User" class and "NSDate" and it works perfectly fine. For "User" class it returns true, and for NSDate class it returns false. Can you think of any case where this logic would not work? If not I think this is a perfect solution I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I suppose it might not work on a class created at runtime with `objc_allocateClassPair`, or a [class created by KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002307-BAJEAIEE).  You'll have to test those yourself if you think they will be an issue.  You probably won't encounter them though.

Comment: Thanks again. great answer, and great referencing